# With django-ckeditor how would I dynamically set CKEDITOR_FILENAME_GENERATOR based on app name?

Tags: django, ckeditor

I'd like to be able to have a custom CKEDITOR_FILENAME_GENERATOR for one particular app while also having a default for all other apps. My first though was to dynamically set by app name somehow. Would something like the following be possible:

```
#settings.py
...
def filename_generator():
    fng = 'myproject.custom_filename'
    if app_name = "blog"    #<<<--- how would I achieve something like this?
        fng = 'blog.custom_filename'
    return fng
CKEDITOR_FILENAME_GENERATOR = filename_generator()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The settings.py file is static for the entire project. The best practice here is to use the django {appname}/conf.py file to generate app specific settings:

```
from django.conf import settings
from appconf import AppConf

class MyAppConf(AppConf):
    CKEDITOR_FILENAME_GENERATOR = filename_generator()
```